# Why does my jQuery Autocomplete show results top left of the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following code cobbled together from the jQuery docs and other Google hits. When I type a letter in the auto-complete, it always shows its results at the very top left of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Complete</title>
  <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="autoResults" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <label for="Engineer">Select an Engineer: </label>
    <input id="Engineer">
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#Engineer").autocomplete({
        @ * source: "@Url.Action("
        AutoCompleteOrgList ", "
        ContractManagement ")" * @
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
        appendTo: "#autoResults",
        position: {
          my: "left top",
          at: "left bottom"
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is most likely a CSS problem. Is the autocomplete container, or one of its parents, positioned absolutely, or fixed?

Comment: The autocomplete container is not explicitly positioned at all, just relative to the input with `left top` and `left bottom`. These seem to be ignored and make no difference from when they were not present.

Comment: @ProfK Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem